# Is this sentence correct? "It was two years ago I first met her"

Tags: word-usage

Is this sentence correct? "It was two years ago I first met her".

I think 'ago' is not suitable here. I replaced 'ago' by 'since': "It was two years since I first met her". Are both the sentences correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Ago" is fine.  The sentence is fine as written.

Note this is a slightly *dramatic* way to phrase this statement, since it inverts the usual phrasing, "I first met her two years ago."

Other examples of this:

> It was ten years ago today that I had my last drink.
>
> Twenty years ago (when I was a much younger and consequentially more foolish man) was when I first laid eyes on the woman who was to be my wife.
>
> Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.

This structure is "dramatic" because it does not reveal the *subject* of the sentence until the end, after you describe how much time has passed.  It's not something people say in ordinary conversation, unless they want to be seen as a particularly dramatic person.  But it does show up frequently in novels, songs, films, etc.